# association_id in setter method when created with a has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to call the association_id (site_id in my case) attribute in a setter method, but I get nil when the object is created with a has_many relation.

A site has many domains, and one primary_domain. The primary domain is determined with a primary_id attribute. All domains for a given site have the same primary_id.

My Domain class:

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site

  def is_primary=(bool)
    if bool
      self.save if !self.id.present?
      Domain.where(site_id: self.site_id).update_all(primary_id: self.id)
    end
    true
  end
end
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
@site.domains.create(domain: "www.example.com", is_primary: true)
```

When I call `self.site_id` in the `is_primary=` setter method, it returns nil. It seems I can't get self.site_id in the setter method it it's not explicitly specified. Sure, I can explicitly set the attribute myself, but I feel I'm missing something. I'd think this should be possible, with the rails conventions about relations and Activerecord querying and all.

So, any ideas on how I get the site_id attribute in this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to mess with `create`'s saving process, interrupting it midway (by calling `save` in the middle of it).

Just make a callback:

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site

  attr_accessor :is_primary

  after_commit :set_primary, if: :is_primary

  def set_primary
    Domain.where(site_id: self.site_id).update_all(primary_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I ended up doing it after I posted this. Still, it's kind of a shame I can't get the site_id attr when the object is created through a has_many relation, apparently.

Comment: You can try building object first: `domain = @site.domains.build; domain.update(domain: 'example.com', is_primary: true)`. That will work. Still, my advice holds: don't interrupt ActiveRecord's saving process. Use callbacks to mess with it instead.